# how to use relationship in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

i have a Order and OrderProductDetail model

```
    class Order(models.Model):
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        is_paid = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='پرداخت شده / نشده')
        payment_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='تاریخ پرداخت')

   class OrderProductDetail(models.Model):
        order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='سبد خرید')
        product = models.ForeignKey(Mahsoolat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='محصول')
        price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='قیمت محصول')
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="تاریخ ثبت", default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

in views.py (orders have two items)

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id, is_paid=True)
```

at each item of orders contain several items
now how can i retrieve all items of orders that exist in OrderProductDetail model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Something in a line of

```
OrderProductDetail.objects.filter(order__owner=request.user.id, order__is_paid=True)
```